# How to test that an error does not occur?

Tags: r, testing

I am starting to implement testing for an R package, and have been using the `testthat` package. Note that I am new to testing, so perhaps my approach is off.

I have a function that currently fails the 16th time it is executed, and before fixing this, I want to write a regression test that will catch it if it re-appears.

e.g., the following always throws the same error message:

```
 for i in (1:17) myfun()
```

`myfun` does not return anything, it only has a side-effect of opening a database connection. It is clear to me that I can write a test that expects an error and passes if it is returned:

```
 expect_error(for (i in 1:17) myfun())
```

But I don't quite get how to write a test to ensure that the error does not occur. As it is not obvious, perhaps my approach is wrong. I can figure out how to write more specific tests, but I would like to start with this one.

What type of test would I write to make sure that such an error does not appear?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

**Major edit due to changes in testthat**

Since version 0.11 (via [RStudio blog](https://blog.rstudio.org/2015/10/15/testthat-0-11-0/)) there is direct support to testing lack of errors:

```
expect_error(myfun(), NA)
```

Same for catching `warning` and `message`:

```
expect_warning(myfun(), NA)
expect_message(myfun(), NA)
```

Side note: There is an `info` parameter in `expect_xxx` functions to pass additional info. So you can do:

```
for (i in 1:17) expect_error(myfun(), NA, info = paste("i =", i))
```

Comment: Please note well that this must be `NA` (i.e. _`logical`_ `NA`), _not_ `NA_character_`

Answer (score 10):

Maybe wrap it with another expect_error.

Example:

```
expect_error(1)
expect_error(expect_error(1))
```

Comment: It does not seem to be working anymore (version 1.0.2)

Answer (score 8):

For example:

```
context("test error")
test_that("test error 1", {
  expect_true({log(10); TRUE})
})

test_that("test error 2", {
  expect_true({log("a"); TRUE})
})
```

will test if there is an error.

```
> test_file("x.r")
test error : .1


    1. Error: test error 2 -------------------------
    Non-numeric argument to mathematical function
    1: expect_true({
           log("a")
        TRUE
    })
    2: expect_that(object, is_true(), info, label)
    3: condition(object)
    4: expectation(identical(x, TRUE), "isn't true")
    5: identical(x, TRUE)
```

this means the first part passed the test while the second part failed.

Comment: thanks, but I am not familiar with the use of the curly braces and semi-colon inside the expectation (e.g. `expect_true({...;...})`) could you please explain?

Comment: You can put any expression there. And the `{...; ...; ...}` is just an expression. So in you case, it should be written as `expect_true({for (i in 1:17) {myfun()}; TRUE})`.

Comment: So this is basically trying to catch an error, since an error would prevent the second part of the expression (in this case, `TRUE`) from being evaluated?

Comment: Yes, exactly. TRUE can be replaced by any value.

Comment: I like the simplicity now that I understand

Answer (score 4):

Here is one solution using the expectation that `tryCatch` returns `0` when the error does not occur:

```
expect_equal(tryCatch(for(i in 1:17) myfun()), 0)
```